# How to compare two pointers?

Tags: rust

I want to compare two pointers within this loop:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    first: i32,
    second: i32
}

fn main() {
    let test = vec![Test {first: 1, second: 2}, Test {first: 3, second: 4}, Test {first: 5, second: 6}];

    for item in test.iter() {
        println!("---                  {:?}", item);
        println!("item                 {:p}", item);
        println!("test.last().unwrap() {:p}", test.last().unwrap());

        //  if item == test.last().unwrap() {
        //      println!("Last item!");
        //  }
    }
}
```

The `println` gives me the same addresses:

```
---                  Test { first: 1, second: 2 }
item                 0x563caaf3bb40
test.last().unwrap() 0x563caaf3bb50
---                  Test { first: 3, second: 4 }
item                 0x563caaf3bb48
test.last().unwrap() 0x563caaf3bb50
---                  Test { first: 5, second: 6 }
item                 0x563caaf3bb50
test.last().unwrap() 0x563caaf3bb50
```

But when I uncomment the `if` statement the following error is thrown:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `&Test`
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
20 |         if item == test.last().unwrap() {
   |            ---- ^^ -------------------- &Test
   |            |
   |            &Test
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `&Test`
```

How can I compare only the two pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you compare pointers you are actually comparing the values pointed by those. This is because there are a lot of implementations in `std` of the type:

```
impl<'_, '_, A, B> PartialEq<&'_ B> for &'_ A
where
    A: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
    B: ?Sized,
```

that do exactly that.

If you want to compare the pointers themselves you can use [`std::ptr::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html):

```
pub fn eq<T: ?Sized>(a: *const T, b: *const T) -> bool
```

Note that even though it takes raw pointers, it is safe because it does not dereference the pointers. Since there is an automatic coercion from a reference to a raw pointer, you can use:

```
if std::ptr::eq(item, test.last().unwrap()) {
    println!("Last item!");
}
```

Comment: I might clarify in your answer that by "normal pointer" you mean a reference, to help disambiguate things

Comment: That whole "safe unless dereferenced" rule sounded strange and unnecessary when I first heard about it (why do that when you could make the type itself unsafe to use?) but this use case makes it sound way more reasonable...